# SQL queries - not getting the proper result from Like statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Table name: student:

```
id    name     topics
---   ----     --------
1     Test1    1,2,10,15,25
2     Test2    5,21,11,18,13
3     Test3    2,1,16,25,10
4     Test4    2
```

My query:

```
select * from student where topics like '%2%'
```

output: all 4 records.
Expected: But i need to get only 3 record since that id 1,3,4  topics column contains 2. 2nd record doesn't contain 2 .

Comment: It technically  contains 2 that is 21 having 2. Your wild card searches for 2 only.

Comment: The 2 in 25 & 21 is like %2%.  You should never store delimited values in a column, you should use a one-to-many intermediate table with multiple studentId -> topic rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function FIND_IN_SET :

```
select * from student where FIND_IN_SET ('2', topics)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second record DOES contain 2.
You need to use something like this.

```
WHere topics=2 or topics like '2,%'or topics like '%,2' or topics like '%,2,%'
```

The first checks if topics is 2. THe second if 2 is the first, but there are others. THe third checks if  2 is the last, but there are some numbers before, and the forth checks if 2 is somewhere in between

Answer (score 0):

Something like that might help?

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE topics LIKE '2,%' OR topics LIKE '%,2,%' OR topics LIKE '%,2' OR topics= '2';
```

its sad that you cant use IN  with LIKE.